# Delegates vs methods - why I got the strange result

Tags: c#, .net, performance, delegates, performance-testing

When I implemented xxHash, I try to use inline assembly as "ROL" operation. Here is my test code:

```
class Program
{
    private delegate uint RolFunc(uint x, int y);
    private static readonly byte[] _AsmCodeROL64 = new byte[] { 0x8B, 0xC1, 0x8B, 0xCA, 0xD3, 0xC0, 0xC3 };
    /*X64 ASM
    8B C1                - mov eax,ecx
    8B CA                - mov ecx,edx
    D3 C0                - rol eax,cl
    C3                   - ret 
    */
    private static readonly byte[] _AsmCodeROL32 = new byte[] { 0x8B, 0x44, 0x24, 0x08, 0x8B, 0x4C, 0x24, 0x04, 0xD3, 0xC0, 0xC2, 0x08, 0x00 };
    /*X86 ASM
    8B 44 24 08           - mov eax,[esp+08]
    8B 4C 24 04           - mov ecx,[esp+04]
    D3 C0                 - rol eax,cl
    C2 0800               - ret 0008
    */
    private static readonly RolFunc AsmRol;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private unsafe static extern bool VirtualProtectEx([In] IntPtr hProcess, [In] void* lpAddress, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysUInt)] UIntPtr dwSize, [In] uint flNewProtect, [Out] out uint lpflOldProtect);

    private const uint PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40;

    private static uint RotateLeft32(uint value, int count)
    {
        return (value << count) | (value >> (32 - count));
    }


    static unsafe Program()
    {
        var asmCodeROL = IntPtr.Size == 4 ? _AsmCodeROL32 : _AsmCodeROL64;
        fixed (void* funcAddr = asmCodeROL)
        {
            VirtualProtectEx(GetCurrentProcess(), funcAddr, (UIntPtr)asmCodeROL.Length, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, out var lastProtect);
            AsmRol = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<RolFunc>(new IntPtr(funcAddr));
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        var asmResult = AsmRol(10, 2);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        var mtdResult = RotateLeft32(10, 2);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        asmResult = AsmRol(11, 2);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        mtdResult = RotateLeft32(11, 2);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        asmResult = AsmRol(12, 2);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        mtdResult = RotateLeft32(12, 2);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (uint i = 0; i < 0x10000; i++)
        {
            asmResult = AsmRol(i, 2);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (uint i = 0; i < 0x10000; i++)
        {
            mtdResult = RotateLeft32(i, 2);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

And the result is below:

> 0.0108
>   0.4562
>   0.002
>   0.0008
>   0.0014
>   0.0008
>   8.892
>   0.9648

I found that the code length of inline assembly is much shorter than the method,  but why except for the first time, the AsmRol is much slower than RotateLeft32 ?

Comment: First of all what exactly are you trying to achieve with this test? The only valid perf test is in production, this sort of micro optimization is pointless 90% of the time and when is necessary testing like this is not valid, that's because you can have extremely different results under high loads or different processors.

Comment: Hi @FilipCordas , actually I want to test if the optimization is effective. I have tested it with  DEBUG, RELEASE, X86, X64……but the reslut is SAME, optimization fails. It seems that the delegate may takes more time in the dark. but I also need a reliable argument.

Comment: Again this test doesn't test "performance" at all nor it gives you real results "performance" is not only speed in a console application. I don't find the results that strange there is a price of using export functions but honestly your test is so unreliable that it's hard to tell if what is going on. Probably the first slow execution has to do with JIT and if the last result is ture the .net compiler did some optimization to make it run fast. In general stuff like unsafe code are slower then c# code unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: If you really think you need micro benchmarks try using (BenchmarkDotNet)[https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet ] to get a more reliable picture

Comment: Hi, @FilipCordas ,thank your for your  continuously reply. I have got the reason: instead of calling Delegates, the extra overhead of this scene mainly dues to invoke the native methods.